# 'from' attribute in delay element of MUC history message has jid of occupant instead of room

Tags: ejabberd, multiuserchat

I am observing that from attribute of delay element in MUC history message has JID of the occupant instead of room.

**As per xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-history:**

Discussion history messages MUST be stamped with Delayed Delivery (XEP-0203)  [14]
 information qualified by the 'urn:xmpp:delay' namespace to indicate 
that they are sent with delayed delivery and to specify the times at 
which they were originally sent.

> The 'from' attribute MUST be set to the  JID of the room itself.

```
RoomJID = testGroup@conference.example.com
Occupant 1 = erik@example.com/desktop
Occupant 2 = cyrus@example.com/desktop


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message xmlns="jabber:client" from="testGroup@conference.example.com/cyrus" to="erik@example.com/desktop" type="groupchat">
   <body>Hi</body>
   <thread>B9D31734-606D-43CD-B613-D5FF8DF7CAA3</thread>
   <subject />
   <active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates" />
   <delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" from="cyrus@example.com/desktop" stamp="2015-03-08T21:02:42.481Z" />
   <x xmlns="jabber:x:delay" from="cyrus@example.com/desktop" stamp="20150308T21:02:42" />
</message>
```

Why is it set to the JID of occupant instead of JID of room? Please help me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if you configured your room as anonymous or not. Configure that room as anonymous and it will behave as you expect.

The behaviour you mention is from XEP-0045 v1.25. For non-anonymous room the original from field should be defined with Extended Stanza Addressing.

Changes are not yet supported, but there are work in progress: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/465

Comment: my room is members-only...so it is non-anonymous....I need to have members-only....can not support anonymous yet...also I did not quite understand your second line/paragraph...please elaborate

Comment: I mean, mod muc is not yet adapted to latest XEP version, but it will come someday.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifications